# Making connection to Zookeeper from AuthenticationProvider in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm making `AuthenticationProvider` that during authentication connects to Zookeeper (the same it is running on) and check in node if this user gave correct password.

Basically the flow looks smth like this:

```
@Override
public KeeperException.Code handleAuthentication(ServerCnxn cnxn, byte[] authData) {
        final String usernameColonPassword = new String(authData);
        String[] split = usernameColonPassword.split(":");
        final String username = split[0];
        final String password = split[1];

        byte[] binary = curator.getData().forPath(ATUH_NODE); // here error is thrown
        // check is password is correct
}
```

The problem is that all the time I'm getting `KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss` at line when curator get data. What is the reason of this behavior? During an authentication I'm not allowed to do connection to Zookeeper that is authorizing client?

Below full stacktrace:

```
    org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for XXX
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:172)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:161)
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:157)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:148)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found it is impossible. At this point zookeeper is having some kind of lock/semaphore and he's not accepting new connections from this thread.